# Updating basic fields with Jira SOAP API

Tags: c#, api, soap, jira

I am working with the Jira SOAP API, and I have managed to read from an issue and to create new issues. However, I am having trouble with updating the fields of an already existing issue. I make changes to the fields, but they do not persist after the program stops running.

I know that the method to use is likely the updateIssue(...) method, but I haven't been able to attempt using it, as I don't know what to pass for the last parameter. I looked at the documentation, but don't understand what the RemoteFieldValue[] is.

Can someone please tell me how I could create a RemoteFieldValue[] that I could pass to the updateIssue method in order to update basic fields like summary, description, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have seen code samples about how to update custom fields. I think that my problem would be solved if I knew what the field keys were for non-custom fields. I know that for custom fields, you set the keys and can then use them. But how do I find the key value for a standard field?

Comment: What language are you using to write your SOAP requests?

Comment: I am using c# in visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update basic fields using Jira SOAP you need to use updateIssue() (as you suspected).

```
updateIssue(java.lang.String token, java.lang.String issueKey, RemoteFieldValue[] actionParams)
```

RemoteFieldValue constructor takes two parameters: fieldID and newFieldValues

```
public RemoteFieldValue(java.lang.String fieldID,
                        java.lang.String[] newFieldValues)
```

Where fieldID for standard fields is a name of the field ("summary", "description", etc.)

Here is an example:

```
List<RemoteFieldValue> actionParams = new List<RemoteFieldValue>();

RemoteFieldValue description = new RemoteFieldValue { 
    id = "description", 
    values = new string[] { "here is new description" } };

actionParams.Add(description);

jiraSoapService.updateIssue(token, issueKey, actionParams.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this -it worked with no further problems. If you are inclined, could you tell me how I could change the status of an issue using the progressWorkFlowAction method? I feel like the code must be similar, but even after seeing this, I can't make it work. Isn't actionParams the same for the progressWorkFlowAction method as for updateIssue? Then couldn't I pass null if I only wanted the status changed and nothing else? Thanks again for the help above, and if you think my status question above should be a different question entirely, let me know and I will create a new question.

Comment: Status transition may allow editing some fields (depending on the Jira workflow you have). Some of these fields may be required. So actionParams in progressWorkFlowAction method are those fields that you can edit from the screen when you transition Jira issue manually. If there are no required fields for transition, then you can pass null as actionParams.